# JAX-WS response read entity type

Tags: java, jax-ws, resteasy

A rest easy client gets a response from a WS (deployed in an  external WAR file).

In case of error, a 400 status code is returned plus the exception as the response's body:

```
return Response
        .status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        .entity(new CustomException())
        .build();
```

Need to find out the type of the exception (Which specific class that inherits Exception) in order to return a meaningful message to the user.

But response.readEntity requires an especific class type rather than a generic one:

```
Exception e =  response.readEntity(Exception.class);
```

As I don´t know when calling readEntity the class type, how can readEntity return the specific instance for any type extending Exception (including Exception)? Or instead, find the body entity class type before reading it.

Comment: What do you mean by "Exception" as response body? Does it contain the stacktrace,? does it contain exception name? Could you post the response body in your post?

Comment: I meant an instance of my custom exception (any class extending java.lang.Exception). Edited the post. Hope it is clearer.